# How to set a base case in Erlang

Tags: loops, recursion, erlang

I am currently trying to set a base case in Erlang for a recursive step, however, whenever I do, I end up with the warning `variable New_Array is unused`. I am curious about how I would go about setting a base case for this function, as it seems when I set mine it defaults to running the base case instead recursing first.

```
% base case
function(List, Array, 0) ->
    print_board(Array);

function(List, Array, Size) ->
    % do stuff here
    New_Array = Array,
    function(List, Array, Size-1).
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang is checking if you declare a variable but not use it. It is an interesting warning that must be analyzed, because it often points an issue in your program.

In the case of your first clause, you detect the base case of the recursion because size is 0, and in this case only wants to return the variable Array. The first parameter of the function is useless in this case. To indicate this to Erlang, you can name the variable `_` or `_List`.

```
% base case
function(_List, Array, 0) ->
    print_board(Array);

function(List, Array, Size) ->
    % do stuff here
    New_Array = Array, %% the compiler will complain also because New_Array is unused
    function(List, Array, Size-1).
```

Comment: Thanks! That suppressed one of the warnings, but I am still getting the warning from `New_Array`, it appears that the function always runs the base case and never the main part of the function.

Comment: There more than the unused variable problem to solve here, but you could start by using New_Array as parameter of the recursion call : `function(List,New_Array,Size-1)`. It won't do anything, but at least the function will finish if you call it first with a positive integer.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly, everything works now, I can't believe I forgot to send New_Array into the recursive function, thanks for the help!

Comment: That's why it is interesting to look at this kind of warning! It happens to me quite often when I copy/paste the clauses and forget to update some of them...